# Programmatically pair bluetooth devices

Tags: android

```
package com.example.bt02_connect;
import java.lang.reflect.Method;

 import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
 import android.bluetooth.BluetoothAdapter;
 import android.bluetooth.BluetoothDevice;
 import android.content.Intent;
 import android.os.Bundle;
 import android.util.Log;
 import android.view.View;
 import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
 import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
 import android.widget.Button;
 import android.widget.Toast;
 public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity implements OnClickListener {
private Button button1;
private Button button2;
private  ArrayAdapter<String> btArrayAdapter;
private BluetoothAdapter mBluetoothAdapter = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    button1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
    button1.setOnClickListener(this);
    button2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);
    button2.setOnClickListener(this);
}   

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {  
    int id = v.getId();
     if (id == R.id.button1) {
         if (!mBluetoothAdapter.isEnabled()) {
         mBluetoothAdapter.enable();
             }
         }
      else if (id== R.id.button2) {
      btArrayAdapter.clear(); 
      mBluetoothAdapter.startDiscovery();
      Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Scanning Devices", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
        }
        }
```

Im trying to make it on button 2 to scan the devices,
It doesn't show me the toast so something wrong with this button.. I guess that's the problem.
      I fixed the problem with the button2 , now when I click it its crashing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do not just copy/paste some code you found somewhere else.

1. Check your brackets. You are missing many of them.
2. Define the function `pairDevice()` outside of `onClick` and call it on `onClick`.

Comment: look at the edit, something is wrong with my button. ty anyway

Comment: Your brackets are still placed wrong. e.g. you don't close your first if condition before the else if condition. Thats why the code is never executed.

Comment: You forgot to initialize your ArrayAdapter.

Answer (score 0):

```
ublic void pairDevice(BluetoothDevice device)
{
    String ACTION_PAIRING_REQUEST = "android.bluetooth.device.action.PAIRING_REQUEST";
    Intent intent = new Intent(ACTION_PAIRING_REQUEST);
    String EXTRA_DEVICE = "android.bluetooth.device.extra.DEVICE";
    intent.putExtra(EXTRA_DEVICE, device);
    String EXTRA_PAIRING_VARIANT = "android.bluetooth.device.extra.PAIRING_VARIANT";
    int PAIRING_VARIANT_PIN = 0;
    intent.putExtra(EXTRA_PAIRING_VARIANT, PAIRING_VARIANT_PIN);
    intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
    context.startActivity(intent);
}

Intent intent = new Intent(BluetoothDevice.ACTION_PAIRING_REQUEST);
intent.putExtra(EXTRA_DEVICE, device);
int PAIRING_VARIANT_PIN = 272;
intent.putExtra(BluetoothDevice.EXTRA_PAIRING_VARIANT, PAIRING_VARIANT_PIN);
sendBroadcast(intent);

Intent intent = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_BLUETOOTH_SETTINGS);
startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_PAIR_DEVICE);
```

---

I hope this helps

Reference: http://pastebin.com/N8dR4Aa1